# WPF ToolTip Placement Target returns null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
<DataTemplate>                                
    <Border>
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip IsEnabled="True"
                     Placement="Right">
                <ToolTip.VerticalOffset>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OffsetConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="Vertical">
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </ToolTip.VerticalOffset>
            <TextBlock Margin="0" 
                       Padding="0"
                       TextAlignment="Left"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       MaxWidth="200"
                       Text="{Binding Description}" FontStyle="Italic">
                </TextBlock>
            </ToolTip>
        </Border.ToolTip>                                    
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
            <Image Height="16" Width="16" Style="{StaticResource AutoCompletionImageStyle}" Margin="0"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding DisplayText}" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

And this converter :

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        AutoCompletionViewModel.OffsetType offsetType = (AutoCompletionViewModel.OffsetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AutoCompletionViewModel.OffsetType), parameter.ToString());
        ToolTip tooltip = values[0] as ToolTip;
        Border border = tooltip.PlacementTarget as Border;

        double aCalculatedOffset = 0.0;
        return aCalculatedOffset;
    }
```

I need to calculate the offset of the tooltip based on some properties of the Border. The tooltip appears relative to the border and manually changing the offset works as expected. However when I try to access the `PlacementTarget` property of the ToolTip in the converter it is null...

So, although the ToolTip is a direct child of the Border and should have it as a placement target, in the code it is null. Any idea what I am missing here?

I also tried passing the border with `<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}"/>` to no avail.

I am really confused since, if the border is not the logical or visual parent of the ToolTip how does the ToolTip places itself correctly?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround :

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border ToolTipOpening="OnAutoCompletionBorderToolTipOpening">
        <Border.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <ToolTip.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <EventSetter Event="ToolTip.Opened" Handler="ToolTipOpenedHandler" />
                    </Style>
                </ToolTip.Style>
            </ToolTip>
        </Border.ToolTip>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ToolTipOpenedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip toolTip  = (ToolTip)sender;
    UIElement target = toolTip.PlacementTarget;
    var rect = toolTip.PlacementRectangle;

}
```

The target here is not null, rather the Border...

I am pretty sure this is some WPF bug. Hopefully someone will be helped by this post.